# IS it possible to create a new event using J2me?

Tags: events, java-me

I want to create my own event in j2me. Is that possible to create one? I've been googling for a solution but could not find much on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Hi Try Following code to create event in J2ME...& Please Refer jsr 75

```
EventList eventList = (EventList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);

Event event = eventList.createEvent();
...
event.addString(Event.SUMMARY, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, summary);
...
event.commit();
```